# IF user in not on database add him, IF it is dont do nothing

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I have seen a lot of answers but none worked for me, I think what I want is something different.
Im making a website that organises a battle in a game (Clash of Clans), so the user can select what base ($base) the user ($name) is going to attack.
In the page, the user can choose the number of the base in a select list, and type his name. So if no one has choosen that number before (the number was not in the database), his name that number will be stored there. But if the number is already on the list, the user CANT update or change this.
In less words:
IF $number is already on the database: do nothing, IF is not: INSERT him
And now here is the code of the webpage:

```
 $base = $_POST['base'];
   $nome = $_POST['nome'];


$sql = 
"
//Here is the code that I need to check if the number do not exists and add it
";

mysql_select_db('a2322671_spabr');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Numero da base</td>
<td>
<select name="base" id="base">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Quem vai atacar</td>
<td><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Reservar">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

I thanks from now and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are base and nome 2 different columns or combined into one column seperated by a comma or dash?

Comment: Base and nome are two different colums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
mysql_select_db('a2322671_spabr');

$base = $_POST['base'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$retval = mysql_query("SELECT base FROM bases_table WHERE base = '$base'", $conn);

if (mysql_num_rows($retval) == 0) {
    // doesn't exist already, do stuff
    $retval2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bases_table (base, nome) VALUES ('$base' , '$nome')", $conn);
    if(!$retval2) {
        die('Could not enter data: '.mysql_error());
    }

    echo "Data inserted successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);

} else {
    // does exist, do something else
    echo "Data already exists.";
    mysql_close($conn);
}
```

I will btw advise against using the builtin mysql features for the purpose of them being both unsafe and deprecated. Take a look on [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I get this error when I use your code

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a2322671/public_html/update.html on line 26

Comment: I am so sorry.. Apparently I suck with semicolons today, I forgot one on the first line. I edited my suggestions, and you should check for semicolon mistakes :)
Also I do not know what you have in update.html on line 26, so if you get errors then put them in pastebin or edit the original post with additions so we can see the mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, im a little bit noob. But I feel that I need to remove something on * that part becouse "mysql_query" is already included in the variable $sql. The code is on the other comment. Please help me solving this issue.

Comment: I cant paste a formated code here in the comments, so here is the pastebin link to the code
http://pastebin.com/N2DWvrh6

Comment: There is multiple reasons why that fails.
SQL not being executed before a row check, and text not assigned to a variable to be executed.
Anyway, check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! it worked, the errors got away, but now only a strange error, but I think that easy to solve. I think its a bracket or a semicolon.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/a2322671/public_html/update.html on line 83
http://pastebin.com/hUBaQLG3 
Updated with role code

Comment: You are correct, it's a bracket problem. On line 41 you have an opening bracket, that should be a closing bracket to close the if statement on line 7.
Remove line 68-70, that closing bracket is now on line 41.

Comment: Thanks man! You are the best, thanks for the patience, now everythng is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT IGNORE" statement should serve you well in this situation.

```
$sql ="INSERT IGNORE INTO baseTable ('baseId','userName') VALUES('$baseId', '$userName')";

mysql_select_db('a2322671_spabr');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if($retval )
{
   echo "Entered data successfully\n";
}
mysql_close($conn);
```